# Aligning column headers above a listview

Tags: android-layout

I am having some trouble aligning some headers above a listview.

This is what my layout looks like:

[image]

I would like to align the headers above their respective buttons.

My layout code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutTimeRange">
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinnerTimeRange" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/plus_white_32"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonAddTimeRange" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <TableLayout
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:text="DATE"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView
                android:text="ON SITE"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView
                android:text="STARTED"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView
                android:text="FINISHED"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewTimeRange"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My list item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayoutTimeRangeItem">
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRowTimeRangeItem">
        <Button
            android:text="Date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/buttonTimeRangeItemDate" />
        <Button
            android:text="Time On Site"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/buttonTimeRangeItemOnSite" />
        <Button
            android:text="Time Started"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/buttonTimeRangeItemStarted" />
        <Button
            android:text="Time Finished"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/buttonTimeRangeItemFinished" />
        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_delete_32"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/buttonTimeRangeItemDelete" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

I really am at a loss about how to do this. I've been battling for quite a while.

Can anybody help?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a TableLayout with a TableRow inside, I'd better use a LinearLayout with weighted children.

In both the header (children weights: 20, 20, 20, 40) and the custom row (children weights: 20, 20, 20, 20, 20).

Keep in mind that all the children widths must be **0dp**, in order for the weights to be applied.

Comment: Your suggestion worked great! Thanks very much for the help :)

Comment: Glad that you could take advantage from my suggestion. ;)